# Azure Redis - Occasional slowness in retrieving specific object

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

Sometimes slowness observed, in retrieving object from Azure Redis cache with key of pattern "http:____my.website.com", whereas time to retrieve object with key "abc_xyz_def_test_test" is almost consistent no spike in retrieving time like in other case mentioned. Size of the both the objects stored against "http:____my.website.com" (or) "abc_xyz_def_test_test" are of almost same. Also verified serializing the object to custom type, not playing foul here.

Is the slowness because of the key pattern? Please clarify. Also how to overcome this slowness issue.

Azure redis P1 tier (without cluster) used in this case. Redis metrics like CPU/Memory are normal as shown in Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [best practices documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices), we need to consider several ways to improve the performance.

- Chopping up bigger data into multiple keys.
- Configure your client library to use a connect timeout of at least 15 seconds.
- Scale up to P2 Premium to get High network bandwith.
- [Configure Redis clustering for a Premium Azure Cache for Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-premium-clustering).